# Return distance in elasticsearch results?

Tags: geolocation, elasticsearch

My question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290057/compute-geo-distance-in-elasticsearch).

Simply, is there a way to return the geo distance when NOT sorting with _geo_distance?

Update:
To clarify, I want the results in random order AND include distance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes you can, by using a [script field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/script-fields.html).

For instance, assuming your doc have a geo-point field called `location`, you could use the following:

(note the `\u0027` is just an escaped single quote, so `\u0027location\u0027` is really `'location'`)

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/geonames/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "script_fields" : {
      "distance" : {
         "params" : {
            "lat" : 2.27,
            "lon" : 50.3
         },
         "script" : "doc[\u0027location\u0027].distanceInKm(lat,lon)"
      }
   }
}
'

# [Thu Feb 16 11:20:29 2012] Response:
# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_score" : 1,
#             "fields" : {
#                "distance" : 466.844095463887
#             },
#             "_index" : "geonames_1318324623",
#             "_id" : "6436641_en",
#             "_type" : "place"
#          },
... etc
```

If you want the `_source` field to be returned as well, then you can specify that as follows:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/geonames/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "fields" : [ "_source" ],
   "script_fields" : {
      "distance" : {
         "params" : {
            "lat" : 2.27,
            "lon" : 50.3
         },
         "script" : "doc[\u0027location\u0027].distanceInKm(lat,lon)"
      }
   }
}
'
```

Comment: However, I'm having trouble getting both _source and distance returned. If I specify _source as "fields" I only get _source, if I don't I only, get distance. Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of ES are you using?  When I wrote this answer, there was a newly introduced bug that meant the source wasn't being returned.  However, that has been fixed in the latest RC

Comment: Oh, that's probably why, I'm on 0.17.5.

Comment: Is it possible to run distanceInKm on an object field? for example: place.point, I've also tried _source.place.point, as I get from the docs that this should be possible? Where place is an nested object. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DrTech, tried to follow your advice with no success, check out what I see: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elasticsearch/59jFsrzG2Hc/zSCfNeVKj5sJ

Comment: unfortunately this fails in the latest version of Elasticsearch (1.2), 1.1 was fine
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

Comment: In elastic 5.x,6.x should using `arcDistance(lat,lon)` or `planeDistance(lat,lon)` methods.

Answer (score 20):

Great answer by DrTech ... here is an updated version for Elasticsearch 5.x with painless as the script language. I also added "store_fields" to include `_source` in the result:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/geonames/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
  "stored_fields" : [ "_source" ],
  "script_fields" : {
    "distance" : {
      "script" : {
        "inline": "doc['location'].arcDistance(params.lat,params.lon) * 0.001",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
          "lat": 2.27,
          "lon": 50.3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Any reason why this would give me a `Variable [venue] is not defined.` for `doc['venue.coordinates']`? Venue.coordinates is a field in object venue, so I'm not sure what's missing.

Comment: this works for 6.x too. You can leave out "lang": "painless" since it's the default.

Comment: The same code will work with 7.9 version                                              
 "stored_fields" : [ "_source" ],
  "script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['pin.location'].arcDistance(28,77);"
      }
    }
  }

Answer (score 14):

To return distance aswel as as all the default fields/source, you could also do this:

To avoid that it sorts by distance (primarily) you just sort by _score (or whatever you want the results sorted by) first.

```
{
   "sort": [
    "_score",
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": { 
          "lat":  40.715,
          "lon": -73.998
        },
        "order":         "asc",
        "unit":          "km", 
        "distance_type": "plane" 
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This solution works also with script support disabled, as is the case on many hosted servers. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since **ES 1.3** MVEL is disabled by default so use a query like:

```
GET some-index/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "geo_location": "47.1, 8.1",
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "m"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
   "script_fields" : {
      "distance" : {
         "lang": "groovy",
         "params" : {
            "lat" : 47.1,
            "lon" : 8.1
         },
         "script" : "doc[\u0027geo_location\u0027].distanceInKm(lat,lon)"
      }
   }
}
```

see: `"lang": "groovy",` part

Comment: can you please tell me how did you enable scripting i mean did you write anything inside your yml file or anything please tell me i am searching this for soo long ??

Comment: can it be set to one of the source field?