# Wrong distance returned by ElasticSearch distanceInKm

Tags: elasticsearch

I've implemented a script field that returns distance like here [Return distance in elasticsearch results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295118/return-distance-in-elasticsearch-results)

Ruby:

```
{
  script_fields: {
    distance: {
      script: "doc['#{source_field}'].distanceInKm(#{lat}, #{lng})"
    }
  }
}
```

However the distance returned isn't correct. If the point is close, the distance is more correct but as it gets further away it gets more and more incorrect.

Can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What does this have to do with RoR?

Comment: I originally included some Rails methods that I used on the distance. Deleted the tag, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

distanceInKm() calculates distance as points on a plane, which is fast but not very accurate. Try using arcDistanceInKm() instead.