# Elasticsearch 5 : sort by price of the closest wholesaler

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-5, geopoints

I have a product nested document containing a list of prices associated to different wholesalers.
Here is a document example :

```
{
    "sku": "065879",
    "name": "My product",
    "price": [
        {
            "wholesaler": "1",
            "location": "drm3btev3",
            "price": "12.34"
        },
        {
            "wholesaler": "2",
            "location": "gbsuv7ztq",
            "price": "45.67"
        },
    ]
}
```

Given a customer's geo point, what is the correct query to get a list of documents sorted by price, using only the closest price for each document ?

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0):

It's not a real answer but the global approach is to use a [nested sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting). Nested sort will allow you to filter the nested document on which you want to apply your sorting.

Then you should in the nested sort filter add a script query that will determine the closest wholesaler. The problem is that you cant work with geohash in painless. But if you convert your geohash to geopoint data type in, you will be able to use script distance features ( example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295351/accessing-nested-property-in-elasticsearch-distance-script) )

Then you could compute the minimal distance by iterating on all nested document and only match the one with the minimal distance.

But I have no idea of the performance impact and detailed implementation.

Good luck !

Comment: Hash was given for editorial convenience. No constraint on location field.
I'll have a look at nested sort and nested filter but not sure it will fit my needs.
When lurking the Internet I found something about "Function Score Query". What do you think ?

Comment: function score query will not allow to sort on the price of the nearest wholesaler. But it could allow you to sort on a mix between price and distance see here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/decay-functions.html

Comment: Thank you for this link. I think function score query is not what I need ; I don't need a configurable decay. This is either the good price too use for sorting, or this is not.
I'll go for nested sort + nested filter.