# Using elasticsearch java API in order to compute a distance using the user's geolocation

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I would like to use the java client API in order to return a computed field in the response of documents.

Specifically, I want a user to pass in a geopoint and use that geopoint in order to compute the distance between that geopoint (passed in the query) and the documents' geopoints (stored in the ES index).

I understand it is easily feasible using a script field as follows:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/geonames/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "script_fields" : {
      "distance" : {
         "params" : {
            "lat" : 2.27,
            "lon" : 50.3
         },
         "script" : "doc[\u0027location\u0027].distanceInKm(lat,lon)"
      }
   }
}
```

The above is quoted from the following SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9309674/536299

Now how do you go about doing this with the java API or Spring Data ES?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below to convert it to java api

```
    import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequestBuilder;

    String script =  "doc[\u0027location\u0027].distanceInKm(lat,lon)";
    Map<String, Object> params = ...

    SearchRequestBuilder esRequestBuilder = new SearchRequestBuilder(<ES_CLIENT>);
    esRequestBuilder.addScriptField("distance", script, params);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @rahulroc, Hummm. But then, is the script field used for all document types? How can I relate a type to the above script field?

Comment: By Type.. you mean the elasticsearch type in an index ? https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type

Comment: Yes and I also mean the java class annotated with spring data es's @org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document annotation.

Comment: You can also specify the type in your entity @Document(indexName="myIndex", type="myType"). Then you can search within a type as curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/<INDEXNAME>/<INDEXTYPE>/_search

Comment: I see. As regards the java api, how is the field added to the @Document?

Comment: what field ? I didnt get this

Comment: I meant the newly created field, the dynamic/script field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107818/discussion-between-rahulroc-and-balteo).