# Elasticsearch failed to run inline script [doc....] using lang groovy

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I'm getting this error when trying to match all in my index, and display the distance between a given geo_point and the query results, I'm using [DrTech's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295118/return-distance-in-elasticsearch-results) answer for the script to display the distance:

this is my DSL query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "lang": "groovy",
      "params": {
        "lat": 2.27,
        "lon": 50.3
      },
      "script": "doc['geo_coordinates'].distanceInKm(lat,lon)"
    }
  }
}
```

Query response:

```
{
  "took": 50,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 4,
    "failed": 1,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "users",
        "node": "pa76fjdWQl2YAHmgCT4oKw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "failed to run inline script [doc['geo_coordinates'].distanceInKm(lat,lon)] using lang [groovy]",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "null_pointer_exception",
            "reason": null
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 184,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": []
  }
```

and I have this in my mapping :

```
  "geo_coordinates" : {
            "type" : "geo_point",
            "lat_lon" : true
          },
```

so I don't understand why I'm getting a Null pointer !! .....

Comment: Is it possible that one of your documents has no `geo_coordinates` field ?

Comment: Impossible it does exist in my Mongodb and in my Elasticsearch mapping

Comment: I'm not talking about the mapping, but if you just have one single document instance which doesn't have any value for this field, that might explain the NPE.

Comment: yes some users have this field without any value !

Comment: There you go, then you should modify your script to only call `distanceInKm()` if the value exists.

Comment: any idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because one of the documents doesn't have any value in the `geo_coordinates` field. Hence, you need to account for this case in your script.

Try this instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "distance": {
      "lang": "groovy",
      "params": {
        "lat": 2.27,
        "lon": 50.3
      },
      "script": "doc['geo_coordinates'] ? doc['geo_coordinates'].distanceInKm(lat,lon) : 0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `"doc['geo_coordinates']?.distanceInKm(lat,lon) ?: 0"` should work as well

Comment: True, that's a shorter groovy way of achieving the same thing.